# new to MVC in dotnet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to MVC in dotnet . can anyone help me by complete study materials or any particular link to help me getting started without confusion.
(P.S: i have prior knowledge on dotnet and worked in visual studio 2010)

I also need to know about the versions of mvc ( MVC2 MVC3 and MVC 4.)
Which one does visual studio 2010 supports?

Comment: I would recommend [Pro ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Professional-Apress/dp/1430242361) book from Apress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First know what is MVC and gain some knowledge for MVC 1,2,3,4

- Look at [Creating NerdDinner.com with Microsoft ASP.NET Model View Controller (MVC)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/conference-presentations/creating-nerddinnercom-with-microsoft-aspnet-model-view-controller-mvc)
- [MVC Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/what-is-mvc)
- [ASP.NET MVC Video's](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos)

---

- Second, Google around to find some good books (you'll find brilliant Video Tutorials esp. from [Pluralsight-training.net](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/)

---

Start Coding with sample

- [Simple Hello World Example](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1297-how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-aspnet-mvc-tutorial-no-1.aspx)
- [ASP-NET-MVC-Quick-Start-Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47829/ASP-NET-MVC-Quick-Start-Tutorial-Create-a-Small-AS)
- [Intro to ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4)

***Lastly, ASP.NET has fabulous video tutorial's like [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store)***

Answer (score 0):

You should try some books on MVC 4. You can find them on Amazon. Also a very good tutorial about MVC 4 is the following

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/

You will learn a lot from it.